# Event registration form does not show submit button when a 100% discount coupon is used

Tags: civievent, cividiscount

I run Civi 4.7.13, and trying to setup an online registration form for a CiviEvent.
When no coupon is used, the event registration submit button is the "Pay Pal Checkout" button.
But when the amount is 0 because a 100% discount coupon is used, there is no paypal button and the registration form cannot be submitted.

Comment: Hi Elad, That sounds annoying! A quick question - did you try setting up a similar event on the demo site and seeing if the problem occurred there? Might be worthwhile doing so (and linking to it from here if possible, to help people answer your question.

Comment: I am trying both in live and on demo.
Here you can see the normal test, no discount, all good.
https://terranova.tamera.org/en/civicrm/event/register?reset=1&action=preview&id=1761

and here you can see the problem with a 100% discount
https://terranova.tamera.org/en/civicrm/event/register?reset=1&action=preview&id=1761&discountcode=yaepxl2a7

Comment: Hey again, by demo site, I meant http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ - sorry - should have been more clear. The reason I asked was because it would then help us work out if it was an issue with CiviCRM core or your specific config. It might be that someone has a better understanding of the issue and can short-circuit this step, but it can be useful. PS. I would recommend against putting any real paypal account info on the demo site.

Comment: Hey again,
thank you for your comment, I tried to setup a paypal payment processor on the demo, but it doesnt allow it without providing with a username, password and signature.
how can i reproduce this problem if i cannot put a real paypal account on the demo?
just to say - with the credit card test processor the bug is not reproduced - the continue button also appears when a 100% discount is applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a bug, but I notice your CiviCRM is 4 versions behind the current one, so I'd update your CiviCRM first before doing anything else.

I have seen some similar issues in the past - when you have an on-site payment processor, there is some logic that hides the payment form when no payment is due. Perhaps in combination with an off-site processor like Paypal Standard, the hiding of the payment form turns into hiding the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

I've also hit upon this issue -- an 100% discount coupon results in a zero $ cost for membership, and the Pay Now/Pay Later radio buttons don't appear, and when the prospective member clicks "Submit" to verify their membership request, they see the error :

0 - Call to a member function getPaymentFormFields() on null

I'm running civiCRM  4.7.27 and civiDiscount 3.3, with the Payment Processor set to PayPal - Website Payments Pro.

Any one have a workaround for this, so that we can offer these free memberships?